# Yii2 Pjax and AssetBundle

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am writing a widget which adds fields to a form dinamycally using Pjax. I order to add the validation rules with YiiActiveForm js, I build the rules on the fly, by getting rules from form attributes and assigning them using:

```
$('#w1').yiiActiveForm('add', attributeRules);
```

and save them to a file located inside my widget assets/js/rules.js, on my run method:

```
public function run() {

        Pjax::begin($this->pjaxOptions);

        $fields = $this->_listFields();

        $this->_setFormRules();

        $view = $this->getView();
        FofAsset::register($view);

        echo $fields;

        Pjax::end();

    }
```

The problem is that it always shows the first version of rules.js (for first field), when adding a second field, rules.js only contains the rules for the first field (the one added to the page). Even though the file on widget/assets/js has the rules for both fields. I am using forceCopy and appendTimestamp on my AssetBundle already.

The issue is that the rules.js file is not being updated after calling Pjax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

Pjax is not build to load same resource more than once, that is why my changes did not work :)

Everyday We learn something new.

I solve it by using inline js with registerJs